# Linear model, Newton's Cooling law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

A thermometer is removed from a room where the temperature is 70 and is taken outside, where the air temperature is 10. After half a minute the thermometer reads 50. What is the reading of the thermometer at t=1 min? How long will it take for the thermometer to reach 15?

$\frac{dT}{dt}=k(T-T_m)$
$\frac{1}{T-T_m}dT=kdt$
$\int \frac{1}{T-T_m}dT=\int k dt$
$\ln{|T-T_m|}=kt+C_1$
$T=C_2e^{kt}+T_m$
Using the initial conditions when the thermostat and inside air are both 70 at t=0
$70=C_2 e^{k(0)}+70$ uh-oh
Where am I going wrong? The thermostat and initial ambience are both 70 aren't they?

By the way, I have a lot of trouble telling if k should be negative or positive (but it always becomes apparent in the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the initial ambient is the outside temperature, you have:
$$70=C_2e^{c\times 0}+10=C_2+10$$
so $C_2=60$.

Also the way you have set up your equations $k<0$ since you need $dT/dt<0$ when $T>T_m$ assuming $T_m$ is the ambient temperature.

Answer (score 0):

The object's initial temperature is $T_0=T(0)=70$ and the outside temperature is
$T_e=10$

Now, the general solution is $T(t)=T_e+(T_0-T_e)e^{-kt}$
$T(t)=10+60e^{-kt}$

Now we know that

$T(0.5)=50=10+60e^{-0.5k}$
$T(1)=T=10+60e^{-k}$

$60e^{-0.5k}=40$
$60e^{-k}=T-10$

Let's substitute $\lambda=e^{-k}\hspace{10 mm}$Then$\hspace{10 mm}\lambda^{0.5}=e^{-0.5k}$

So: $\hspace{10 mm}60\lambda^{0.5}=40\hspace{10 mm}$and$\hspace{10 mm}\lambda^{0.5}=\frac{2}{3}\hspace{10 mm}$and$\hspace{10 mm}\lambda=\frac{4}{9}$

Now: $\hspace{10 mm}60\lambda=T-10\hspace{10 mm}$or$\hspace{10 mm}60(\frac{4}{9})=T-10\hspace{10 mm}$and$\hspace{10 mm}T=36.67^{\circ}C$
is the object's temperature in the first minute

To answer the last part we write

$T(t)=15=10+60e^{-kt}$

$\lambda^{t}=\frac{1}{12}\hspace{10 mm}$or $\hspace{10 mm}(\frac{4}{9})^{t}=\frac{1}{12}\hspace{10 mm}$and$\hspace{10 mm}t=3.06$ min